# Apache CustomLog using Content-Type

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

Using Apache 2.4, I am trying to create a custom log file format which will only log out page views, instead of all request resources (images, css, etc).

The site is built using PHP and therefore the document Content-Type is text/html.

I thought I could just simply do this in my apache conf file:-

```
SetEnvIf   Content-Type  "text/html" pagelog
CustomLog "/var/logs/mycustompagelog.log" combined env=pagelog
```

However, this doesn't log out anything, because the Content-Type is part of the Response, not the Request. Is it possible to log out based on the Request headers? How can this be done?